# How to use rosbag play to paly multiple rosbags which are in a folder with a single command?

Tags: rosbag

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have several rosbags in a folder, and I want to use rosbag play to play them one by one automatically. So what should I do with the name of folder or its path so I can make the use of '' rosbag play'' ?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/216042/how-to-use-rosbag-play-to-paly-multiple-rosbags-which-are-in-a-folder-with-a-single-command-?/) by [metalcell](https://answers.ros.org/users/23606/metalcell/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2015-08-18

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Where exactly is your problem?
You can just do a

> rosbag play *.bag

in your directory.

---

Originally posted by [NEngelhard](https://answers.ros.org/users/18581/nengelhard/) with karma: 3519 on 2015-08-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [metalcell](https://answers.ros.org/users/23606/metalcell/) on 2015-08-20**:
Thanks. This is exactly what I am looking for.

**Comment by [rocketman_7](https://answers.ros.org/users/33518/rocketman_7/) on 2018-02-01**:
Ubuntu 16.04 + ROS kinetic, not seeing this working.

**Comment by [Nachum](https://answers.ros.org/users/2980/nachum/) on 2021-08-23**:
Is there a way that I will have input that it is a new file?

**Comment by [Petros ADLATUS](https://answers.ros.org/users/99003/petros-adlatus/) on 2022-03-24**:
Hey @metalcell can you tell me how you playback all the bag files in a folder please? because the answer of @NEngelhard is in relation to one bag file example_bag_file.bag, or not?